What hardware differences between a Mac Studio and a MacBook Pro might cause differences in performance?
I’m in the enviable position of having a nice wad of cash to spend on a new Mac setup. Since Tensorflow and PyTorch are now both supported by Metal, at least on my 16gb MacBook Air M1 I’m more than tempted by either a basic Mac Studio or a top end 16” MacBook with a minimum of 48Gb Ram and 1Tb SSD with enough left over to add a Mac Studio monitor, mouse and keyboard on top.
So what differences in hardware between the two exist that I should bear in mind to choose between the two beyond the obvious of number of cores? Do I lose anything in performance by gaining portability if I choose the MacBook.

Welcome to Ask Different.  If this gets closed as hardware recommendation, don’t fret as other forums can host discussions where we try to focus on useful answers to a broad audience. I see it as a “good subjective” question as it’s not all about price and there are decent comparisons on the feature differences and capabilities for workloads.

You always lose performance for sustained operations with a portable form factor and battery powered optimizations when all other specifications are equivalent. Unless your top of the line chip on the MacBook Pro is somehow much better than the Studio which has seriously better active cooling and voltage due to extra space and line power at hundred or two hundred volts based on where you are in the world with AC power.

The Mac Studio (2023) with an Apple M2 Max processor scores 2,802 for single-core performance and 14,799 for multi-core performance in the Geekbench 6 CPU Benchmark.
The Mac Studio (2023) with an Apple M2 Ultra processor scores 2,774 for single-core performance and 21,329 for multi-core performance in the Geekbench 6 CPU Benchmark.
The MacBook Pro (16-inch, Nov 2023) with an Apple M3 Pro processor scores scores 3,113 for single-core performance and 15,287 for multi-core performance in the Geekbench 6 CPU Benchmark.
The MacBook Pro (16-inch, Nov 2023) with an Apple M3 Max processor scores 3,128 for single-core performance and 20,956 for multi-core performance in the Geekbench 6 CPU Benchmark.

As you can see the previous generation chip is nearly as fast in the Studio form factor as the next generation chip on a portable both of which have 12 CPU per the benchmark classification. The Ultra-based Studio doubles everything core wise for another $1k US cost but still lags slightly on single core. It owns all the rest in terms of the biggest GPU array and CPU multi-core scores of any M3 chip. You pay a lot for incremental gains here past the basic Mac Studio. Whether any of this ever makes any difference is up to your workload as the portability of the MacBook Pro or sunk cost in that display if you want primarily an external display and extra GPU in the Studio should be how you choose your Mac in my experience.

Interestingly, the benchmarks for the M1 Max Studio and M1 Max MBP are all but identical; though I agree that in 'real world, prolonged usage' etc, the portable will yield.
